# how to activate next div only when current div is valid using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-form-validator, formvalidation-plugin

This is my form. I have divided it into 3 divs

```
    <div id="signup-form">
      <div id="row">
        <form id="signForm">
           <div id="first-form">        
                    <fieldset id="body">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
                            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
                        </fieldset>
                         <a class="next" id="next1" href="#"><span>Next</span></a> 
                    </fieldset>

    </div>
    <div id="second-form">
           <fieldset>
              <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                 <label for="password">Password</label>
                 <input type="password" name="pass_word" id="pass_word" />
            </fieldset>
            <a class="next" id="next2" href="#"><span>Next</span></a> 
    </div>
    <div id="third-form">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="city">City</label>
                            <input type="text" name="user_city" id="user_city" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="college">College</label>
                            <input type="text" name="college" id="college" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="branch">Branch</label>
                            <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" id="signup" value="Sign Up" />
                 </div>
            </form>
         </div>
    </div>
```

These are the validations for my code that I have written. I have used validation.min.js plugin for validating the form

```
    var validator = $("#signForm").validate({
  rules: {
    user_name: "required", 
    user_email: {          
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    mobile: {
      required: true,
      digits:true,
      maxlength:10,
      minlength:10
    },
    pass_word: {
      required: true
    },
    user_city: {
      required: true
    },
    college: {
      required: true
    },
    branch: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    user_name: "Please enter name.",
    user_email: {         
      required: "please enter email",
      email: "please enter valid email"
    },
    mobile: {         
      required: "please enter mobile number",
      email: "please enter valid mobile number",
      maxlength: "mobile number contains 10 digits",
      minlength: "max 10 digits allowed"
    },
    pass_word: "Please enter password.",
    user_city: "Please enter user city.",
    college: "Please enter college.",
    branch: "Please enter branch."
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

I am trying to get the code where initially first only the div `first-form` must be active and the remaining two divs `second-form` and `third-form` must be inactive and when the `next` is clicked in div `first-form` it must check for the validation of all the input elements in `first-form` and if all the elements are valid then only the second div i.e, `second-form` must be active. The same with the `second-form`, until all the input elements in `second-form` are valid the `third-form` must be inactive and must be active only when all the input elements in `second-form` are valid.

When I am trying to search for solution I found http://jsfiddle.net/c2y6r/1/. But in this example the `jquery UI tabs` are used, instead I do not want to use tabs. How can I do this with divs instead of tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $("#signForm").validate({
    rules: {
      user_name: "required",
      user_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      mobile: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        maxlength: 10,
        minlength: 10
      },
      pass_word: {
        required: true
      },
      user_city: {
        required: true
      },
      college: {
        required: true
      },
      branch: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      user_name: "Please enter name.",
      user_email: {
        required: "please enter email",
        email: "please enter valid email"
      },
      mobile: {
        required: "please enter mobile number",
        email: "please enter valid mobile number",
        maxlength: "mobile number contains 10 digits",
        minlength: "max 10 digits allowed"
      },
      pass_word: "Please enter password.",
      user_city: "Please enter user city.",
      college: "Please enter college.",
      branch: "Please enter branch."
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });

  $('#next1, #next2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#signForm').valid()) {
      $($(this).attr('href')).show();
      $(this).closest('.tab').hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#second-form,
#third-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<div id="signup-form">
  <div id="row">
    <form id="signForm">
      <div id="first-form" class="tab">
        <fieldset id="body">
          <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
          </fieldset>
          <a class="next" id="next1" href="#second-form"><span>Next</span></a> 
        </fieldset>

      </div>
      <div id="second-form" class="tab">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="pass_word" id="pass_word" />
        </fieldset>
        <a class="next" id="next2" href="#third-form"><span>Next</span></a> 
      </div>
      <div id="third-form" class="tab">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="city">City</label>
          <input type="text" name="user_city" id="user_city" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="college">College</label>
          <input type="text" name="college" id="college" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="branch">Branch</label>
          <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" />
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="signup" value="Sign Up" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fine. But the divs must not be hidden. All three divs are visible but only one div is active at a time, the remaining two divs are deactivated or to say simply until the current div input fields are valid one should not be able to perform any activity on the next div.